# Restriction of Euclidean metric to group

Tags: metric-spaces, representation-theory, lie-groups

I am reading a paper and I am not so sure about some things. I will explain the setup-

We suppose $(Y,\mu)$ is a probability space with a metric $d_Y$ and $G$ is a compact connected Lie group. Suppose further that $\mathbb{R}^d$ is a representation of $G$, and the image of the representation $G\to GL_d$ lies in the orthogonal group $O_d$.

The paper says that the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ restricts to a pseudometric on $G$.

First of all, what is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$? I can not seem to find anything online for such a metric on matrices. (more on this below)

Secondly, I believe this pseudometric on $G$ is defined as follows: if we denote the representation by $\pi$ and the Euclidean metric by $d_e$, then set $d_G(g,h)=d_e(\pi(g),\pi(h))$. According to Wikipedia, this defines a pseudometric on $G$ if $d_e$ defines a pseudometric on $\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$.

Is this the correct reasoning? If so, why is $d_e$ a pseudometric on $\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$?

Edit: Following the hint from @Travis I think I understand this now. We take the Frobenius inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ and the Euclidean metric induced by this. Defining the metric $d_G$ on $G$ as above only gives us a pseudometric (it only gives us a metric if the representation is faithful).

Comment: **Hint** Consider the bilinear form $\Bbb R^{d, d} \times \Bbb R^{d, d} \to \Bbb R$ defined by $(A, B) \mapsto \operatorname{tr}(B^T A) = \sum_{i, j} a_{ij} b_{ij}$.

Comment: Okay, so the Frobenius inner product is used, with 'Euclidean metric' $d_e(A,B)=\sqrt{(A-B,A-B)}$. I still can not see how this is a pseudometric, though :(